# React - Unexpected token u in JSON at position 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm retrieving  data from s3 , I have set the content type as "application/json" for the file. The call is successful.
In the `network --> response` tab i see data as

```
{
  user: "test"
}
```

[image]

When i call the response.json() , I am getting below Error

```
index.js:1 SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the error message says.  That isn't valid JSON.

JSON [requires quoted keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON):

```
{
  "user": "test"
}
```